# PetaPoco - Property names from a dynamic type

Tags: c#, dynamic, reflection, petapoco

I'm attempting to return names of properties of returned from database dynamic type:

```
var d = mDataAccess.Single<dynamic>("select col1 = 'asd', col2 = 'qwe'");
object o = d;
var props = o.GetType().GetProperties();
int propsCount = props.Count();
```

the propsCount is 0, however I expect to have 2,
in which case the code below would return to me two names: col1 and col2

```
List<string> names = o.GetType().GetProperties().Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

Any ideas why I don't get properties that I expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one could provide a working answer, I'll post the solution that I was able to fix this with.

```cs
var e = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

Sql sql = new Sql("select col1 = 'asd', col2 = 'qwe'");
var d = mDataAccess.Query<dynamic>(sql);

if (d != null && d.Count() > 0)
{
    List<string> cols = new List<string>();
    foreach (var t in d.First())
    {
        cols.Add(t.Key);
    }

    foreach (var key in cols)
    {
        List<string> values = new List<string>();
        foreach (var row in d)
        {
            foreach (var t in row)
            {
                if (t.Key == key) values.Add(t.Value.ToString());
            }
        }
        e.Add(key, values);
    }
}

return e;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're happy with a list of dictionaries, you can use:

```
var results = database.Fetch<dynamic>(sql).Cast<IDictionary<string, object>>().ToList();
```

If you want to transform this into a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`, follow that up with:

```
result.First().Keys.ToDictionary(k => k, k => result.Select(r => r[k].ToString()).ToList());
```

after checking the result count.

Answer (score 0):

Single return ExpandoObject.

You can get names from query by using:

```
(d as IDictionary<String, object>).Keys
List<string> names = (d as IDictionary<String, object>).Keys.ToList();
```

Comment: `(d as IDictionary<String, object>).Keys` returns null. Maybe I should have mentioned that all this is happening in WCF, but I don't think this makes any difference.

Comment: I'm thinking this solution would regularly work, but what makes the difference is that this `dynamic d` variable is coming from database through PetaPoco.

Comment: Shouldn't make a difference. It is returning a ExpandoObject when you put dynamic as the type parameter.

Comment: have you tested your solution? The phrase "should't make a difference" makes it sound like you didn't

Comment: @Dmitry, in your question you used Single<T> instead of Query<T>. ;-)